# Concatenation strings with # between them

Tags: c

I am getting a string input with fgets and need to put # between the words of the string. I get the input with fgets but get the wrong Access violation reading location when I am running the program.

Thanks for the Help!

```
char* replaceChar(char* str, char find, char replace)
{
    char* current_pos;
    current_pos = strchr(str, find);
    while (current_pos!=NULL && (current_pos+(strlen(current_pos))!='\n'))
    {
        *current_pos = replace;
        current_pos = strchr(str, find);
    }
    return str;
}

char* addNumberSign(char* string)
{
    char* delimiters = " ";
    int numOfWords = 0;
    char* word;
    word = strtok(string,delimiters);
    while (word!=NULL)
    {
        numOfWords++;
        word = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    if (numOfWords > 1)
        return replaceChar(string,'\0','#');
    else 
        return string;
}
```

Comment: `replaceChar(string,'\0','#');` How will the function know which `'\0'` terminates the original string? Before `strtok` inserted `'\0'` terminators? Why can't you just have a simple loop that overwites every `' '` with `'#'`?

Comment: `string` is a protected word, you can't use it as variable name.